# Rails Error querying data from Postgres on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just deployed my first app on Heroku with Postgres and I'm getting an error when querying data to the models. It's been working properly with local MySQL database when the app queries this through the controller:

```
SELECT "locations".* 
FROM "locations" 
WHERE (id LIKE '%1%' OR user_id LIKE '%1%')):

 18:   </thead>
 19: 
 20:   <tbody>
 21:     <% @locations.each do |location| %>
 22:       <tr>
 23:         <td><%= location.id %></td>
 24:         <td><%= location.user.name %></td>
 FATAL -- : [e8968d66-5740-4005-9236-fd3e4cc61542] app/views/locations/index.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_locations_index_html_erb___341067609742207438_69941629868780'
```

This is the method that does the search:

```
     def index
    if  params[:search].present?
      @search = params[:search]
      @locations = Location.where('id LIKE ? OR user_id LIKE ?', "%#{@search}%", "%#{@search}%") 
    else 
       @locations = Location.all
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some confusion. You mentioned `Postgres on Heroku` in title while `MySql` in description.

I assumed you are using `Postgres` to write below code.

In case if you are using `MySql` then use `LIKE` in given code.

```
@locations = Location.where("id ILIKE :search OR user_id ILIKE :search", search: "%#{@search}%")
```

Let me know if you find this helpful!!!

Comment: Yes, because since I've deployed in Heroku I had to use Postres but on my PC I was using MySQL to develop, either way, I'll test and give a feedback!

Comment: So I tried as you told but still getting error, not quite the same tho, I'm trying to figure it out, but it was helpful.